# Hoeffding's lemma proof using this entropy definition

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

For a positive random variable $Y$ let $H(Y)=E[Y \log Y]-E[Y] \log E[Y]$. And for random variable $X$ let $m_{X}(\lambda)=E\left[e^{\lambda X}\right]$. Assume that $H\left(e^{\lambda X}\right) \leq \frac{\lambda^{2} \sigma^{2}}{2} m_{X}(\lambda), \quad \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, for some constant $\sigma^{2}<\infty$. I want to show the Hoeffding's lemma using this entropy definition.

$$
E\left[e^{\lambda(X-E[X])}\right] \leq e^{\frac{\lambda^{2} \sigma^{2}}{2}}, \quad \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{+} .
$$

I tried quite a lot but none worked. Have no clue how to show this, can I have some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Use Jensen's inequality with $\phi(t) = t\log(t)$ on the random variable
$$ (X - \mathbb E \left [ X \right]) e^{\lambda \left (X - \mathbb E \left [ X \right] \right)}.$$